# How we deselect list box value from excel sheet using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How we deselect list box value from excel sheet using selenium webdriver

Code Here

```
<div class="col-md-8 blockBox">
<select class="required userroles" message="Select User Role" multiple="yes" size="3" name="UserRoles">
<option value="45"> BIS Super Admin </option>
<option value="7"> BIS Senior Admin </option>
<option selected="" value="3"> Learner </option>
<option value="30"> Manager </option>
<option value="48"> Reporting </option>
<option value="51"> Senior Reporting </option>
<option value="4"> Reporting Manager </option>
<option value="31"> Senior Reporting Manager </option>
<option value="40"> Proctor Manager </option>
<option value="50"> Content Manager </option>
<option value="47"> Admin Manager </option>
<option value="49"> Location Admin </option>
<option value="33"> Course Admin </option>
<option value="42"> Client Admin </option>
<option value="46"> Client Senior Admin </option>
<option value="38"> Public Retail Learner </option>
</select>
</div>
```

Code that read "UserRoles" value from excel sheet here

```
driver.findElement(By.name("UserRoles")).sendKeys(s.getCell(15,rowCnt).getContents());
```

I want to deselect or not selecting "UserRoles" value from excel sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Select](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) for this

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("UserRoles")));
select.deselectAll();
// or
select.deselectByValue("3");
// or
select.deselectByVisibleText("Learner");
```